# Concave Upper Bound of Linear Combination of Exponential function

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

I have $f(x)=a_1e^{b_1 x}+...+a_Ne^{b_N x}$

where 
$ a_i\in \mathbb{R} \ \forall i$,
$b_i\in \mathbb{R_+} \ \forall i$

and N is a finite integer.

Is there any concave function that upper bound $f(x)$ for $x<0$?

Comment: It can be the function itself with some transformation.

Comment: Would you be more specific? Like what kind of transformation

Comment: For example, $g(x) = \sum |a_i|   - \sum |a_i|e^{b_ix} = \sum |a_i|(1-e^{b_ix}) $.